# Port mirroring not working on guest Ubuntu machine over KVM

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, kvm, bridge

Host OS = CetOS 7
Hypervisor = KVM
Guest OS = Ubuntu 20

=======================================================

setup a physical NIC on host OS and configure it as promiscuous mode, capturing any traffic.
when using a bridge NIC to fwd all traffic to a virtual NIC on the guest OS, most of the traffic is not seen on guest although seen on host.

Tried the following:

1. https://serverfault.com/questions/798001/kvm-bridge-for-promisc-interface-ids
2. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking#virtio

Answer (score 1):

The issue is solved in our Lab: pass the SPAN port (of the host - CentOS7) directly to the VM (Ubuntu) without the bridged interface I was able to get all traffic to our platform.

This is the configuration used:

[image: config]